# react bootstrap navbar collapse hamburger button does not show nav items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, hamburger-menu

i have a bootstrap navbar in react and when the screen size gets smaller it colappses the navbar and changes it to a hamburger dropdown but when you click on it it will not show the nav items

here is my whole navbar component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavLink, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"


export default function Navbar(Props) {
    return (

        <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-sm" style={{marginTop: '-10px'}}>
            <Link className="Navbar-brand nav-link text-light col-1 mr-4" to="/">
                Logo
            </Link>
            <div className="row col-10 collapse navbar-collapse navbar-nav " id="navbarNav">
                <NavLink className="nav-item nav-link text-light col-2 mr-4 mr-md-1"  to="/customers">customers</NavLink>
                <NavLink className="nav-item nav-link  text-light col-2 mr-4 mr-md-1" to="/rentals">rentals</NavLink>
                <NavLink className="nav-item nav-link  text-light col-2 mr-4 mr-md-1" to="/movies">movies</NavLink>
            </div>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"/>
        </button>
            <NavLink className="nav-item nav-link text-light col-1 mr-2 mr-md-0 ml-3" to="/login">login</NavLink>
        </nav>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to include jquery and popper.js for working out that dropdown properly.
If you have not installed them, you can do as following-

```
npm install jquery popper.js
```

Now, you include them in index.js file in Project root directory or the same file.
If you want to use it, through out the project, then I suggest you to include them in index.js file(src/index.js).

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
```

Comment: thank you for your answer i did it and now i get an eror and its thrown on collapse.jqueryinterface : TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Comment: I have edited my post. Please make sure, this is the importing order, you follow. Just copy paste, as same as above.

Comment: i did change it and the same eror occurs again by the way jquery and properjs are grayed so index.js does not use them maybe thats the problem